# Two forms where the second reads the first form

Tags: forms

I have two nearly identical forms on a page with two buttons, one for each form.
Now I want the second button to also read data from the fields of the first form and hide the fields of the second form or not have them. How can I do that?

the first form

```
<form:form id="excelform" commandName="tg35FormBackingModel" action="${createExcel}" method="post">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tg35-left"><spring:message code="tg35.fromDate" />
<em title="<spring:message code='tooltip.mandatory' />"
class="mandatory float-right">*</em>
</td>
<td><form:input path="fromDate" cssClass="dateInput" /> <form:errors
cssClass="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" path="fromDate" />
</td>
</tr>
```

...

Comment: I have partly succeeded by making a javascript

$("#Pdf").click(function() {
document.getElementById("pdfform").submit();
});
  
$("#Excel").click(function() {
document.getElementById("pdfform").submit();
});
the same form submits
and have left out the table of the first form

Comment: But the buttons remain in the upper form
Is there anyone who knows how I can the get all buttons on the same line, and all of them working. Now if I put them on the same line only the one who is in the form is working